# singly linked list add/delete

Tags: java, algorithm

I constructed a Singly Linked List like this:

```
public class LinkedList {

public LinkedList head;

String key;
LinkedList link;

public LinkedList(String key) {
    this.key = key;
    this.link = null;
    head = this;
}
public void headAdd(String key) {
    LinkedList temp = head;
    LinkedList newHead = new LinkedList(key);
    newHead.link = temp;
}

public void headDelete() {
head = head.link;
}

public String toString() {
    return key;
}

public static final String CANONICAL_NULL = "null list";
static final String NODE_LEFT = "(";
static final String NODE_RIGHT = ")";

public static String canonical(LinkedList list) {
    if (list == null) {
        return CANONICAL_NULL;
    }
    LinkedList current = list.head;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (current != null) {
        sb.append(NODE_LEFT);
        sb.append(current.key);
        sb.append(NODE_RIGHT);
        current = current.link;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

I want to implement headAdd() and headDelete() methods to this Singly Linked List.
What is the easiest way to do it with using this structure?

**EDIT:**
**Test Cases**

```
TEST:   linkedlist_headDelete_1 
description:    delete from 1-node list 
Correct:    ** null list ** 
Yours: ** null list ** 
5   SUCCESS 

TEST:   linkedlist_headDelete_2 
description:    delete from 2-node list 
Correct:    (b0) 
Yours: ** null list ** 
0   FAILED 

TEST:   linkedlist_headAdd_1 
description:    Add 1-node list 
Correct:    (b0) 
Yours: (b0) 
5   SUCCESS 

TEST:   linkedlist_headAdd_2 
description:    Add 2-node list 
Correct:    (b1)(b0) 
Yours: (b0) 
0   FAILED 

TEST:   linkedlist_headAdd_3 
description:    Add 3-node list 
Correct:    (b2)(b1)(b0) 
Yours: (b0) 
0   FAILED
```

Comment: This mashes up `List` with node, inviting all sorts of inconsistencies. (`String` key is gruesome to represent unanimously - try a list with ")(".)

Comment: @greybeard changed a bit and added test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like the following

```
public void headAdd(String key) {

     //hold old head node
     LinkedList temp = head;

     //create new head node
     LinkedList newHead = new LinkedList(key);
     while(newHead.hasNext())
     {
           newHead = newHead.link;
      }
     //Point new head node to old head node
     newHead.link = temp;

}

public void headDelete() {
     //Update head to be next link
     head = head.link;
}

boolean hasNext(LinkedList node)
{

      //check if node has another link
      if(node.link != null)
           return true;
      return false;
 }
```

Comment: I think your code only "changes" the old head value with the new one. I want to "add" a head-node to this linked list which means, my old head value will be my second node after addition.

Comment: The line "newHead.link = temp" is used to set the new head node's next node to the previous head.

Comment: Added the test cases to original post.
It is still failing 3 out of 5 tests.

Comment: http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/Check out this tutorial. But from your tests when it says for instance add 2 node list you intend for that two node list to become the new head? As in node 2 of that list to point to the old head?

Comment: Yes! When we add a 2-node list, second node will be our old head and first node will be our new head.

Comment: You really should create a separate class for your nodes but from what it seems like you are trying to do I edited the response to hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after slightly changing @sreisman 's code.

```
public void headAdd(String key) {
    LinkedList newHead = new LinkedList(key);
    newHead.link = head;
    head = newHead;
    }

public void headDelete() {
    head = head.link;
}
```

Comment: Since this is so close please consider accepting my answer as correct.